# Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I'm trying migrate my codes from .Net 4.7 to .Net core because I think this is the trend for sharepoint app now. My codes is utilizing CSOM in .NET 4.7. But I'm totally a beginner in .Net Core and Azure AD. I registered my app on Azure AD and got my client id. Now, I only want to test first like get my codes to communicate to my SharePoint site. I'm getting below error now.

```
Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.GetProperty(String propertyName)
   at CSOM_core_test.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\source\repos\csom-core-test\Program.cs:line 37
   at CSOM_core_test.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

And below is my codes:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Net;
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Web;
using System.Security;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSOM_core_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";
            string resource = "removed";
            var clientId = "clientid";            
            var username = "O365 email";            
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            string token = "";

        var pwd = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(string.Empty, GetPwd()).Password;

        var body = $"resource={resource}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username)}&password={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pwd)}";
        using (var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
        {
            var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, stringContent).ContinueWith((response) =>
           {
               return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
           });

            var tokenResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);
            token = tokenResult.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();
        }

        var ctx = new ClientContext(new Uri("https://test.sharepoint.com/"));
        ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
        };

        ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(ctx.Web.Title);



    }

    static SecureString GetPwd()
    {
        var pwd = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in "password")
            pwd.AppendChar(c);

        return pwd;
    }
}
```

}

The result is like below:

```
Result: {
"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: cc136100-1351-4344-8901-0fd3fc022e00\r\nCorrelation ID: 4e0cc404-643e-47d3-a06d-0c52bcd77e22\r\nTimestamp: 2021-08-20 22:10:12Z","error_codes":[50126],"timestamp":"2021-08-20 22:10:12Z","trace_id":"cc136100-1351-4344-8901-0fd3fc022e00","correlation_id":"4e0cc404-643e-47d3-a06d-0c52bcd77e22","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"}
```

Comment: Can you please show example of json you are trying to parse?

Comment: I'm not trying to parse a json. I'm taking this article as a reference. https://helgesmeby.net/2020/06/25/csom-is-finally-available-for-net-core/

Comment: @QihongKuang You are parsing Json here `var tokenResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);`. You may want to add what's in `result` to your question. It will be JSON data.

Comment: @Eric J. You are right. The result looks like. It's like below: Result: {
"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: cc136100-1351-4344-8901-0fd3fc022e00\r\nCorrelation ID: 4e0cc404-643e-47d3-a06d-0c52bcd77e22\r\nTimestamp: 2021-08-20 22:10:12Z","error_codes":[50126],"timestamp":"2021-08-20 22:10:12Z","trace_id":"cc136100-1351-4344-8901-0fd3fc022e00","correlation_id":"4e0cc404-643e-47d3-a06d-0c52bcd77e22","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"}

Comment: There's your problem. You're trying to get `access_token` but it isn't present in the JSON. You should check for any `error` first.